# How can I generate rand inherited class

Tags: c#

so I have to generate random inherited classes

This is my parent class:

```
public class Character{...}
```

And a example of inherited classes

```
public class Warrior : Character{...}
```

And this is my "game" class:

```
public class Game : MonoBehaviour{
List<Character> characters = new List<Character>(); 

void Start(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        characters.Add(new Character()); 
        // HERE I WANT TO GENERATE A WARRIOR, MAGUE, PRIEST ETC...
    }       
}}
```

But I won't to do like this:

```
generate random num

    switch(randomnum){
case ...:
characters.Add(new Warrior()); 
...
...
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

I tried to search the same thing before in StackOverflow, but I didn't find nothing.

Sorry for my bad English, thank you! Have a nice day!

Comment: Use reflection to find all classes that implements your base class. Or keep a manual list of them.

Comment: Isn't it that you want to create objects of different type where the choice is made depending on a random number?

Answer (score 3):

You can use an array of types for example and random on it like this:

```
public class Character { }

public class Warrior : Character { }

public class Mague : Character { }

public class Priest : Character { }

public class Game : MonoBehaviour
{

  private Type[] CharacterTypes
    = { typeof(Warrior), typeof(Mague), typeof(Priest) };

  List<Character> characters = new List<Character>();

  void Start()
  {
    var random = new Random();
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
    {
      var characterType = CharacterTypes[random.Next(CharacterTypes.Length)];
      characters.Add((Character)Activator.CreateInstance(characterType));
    }
  }

}
```

You can also use reflexion to get all Character's subtypes at runtime without creating the list in the code (assuming Character is abstract and don't need to be taken):

```
private List<Type> CharacterTypes = new List<Type>();

var types = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes();
foreach ( Type type in types )
  if ( type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Character)) )
    CharacterTypes.Add(type);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array of factories, and randomly pick a factory from the array:

```
Func<Character>[] factories = new Func<Character>[] {
    () => new Worrior(),
    () => new Mague(),
    () => new Priest()
};

Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  Character c = factories[random.Next(factories.Length)]();
  characters.Add(c);
}
```

This has the advantage over Olivier Rogier's answer that it doesn't involve reflection.

Comment: "but the compiler might give you troubles with the array definition here" - Why?

Comment: @Enigmativity I didn't actually try to compile this, so I suspect defining an array of `Func<Character>` and filling it with delegates that return inheritors of `Character` might be a problem, but I could be wrong.

Comment: You should try to compile (and run where possible) everything you post.

Comment: @Enigmativity now I actually compiled (at https://dotnetfiddle.net) and it works.

Comment: So take out the massage about the compiler giving troubles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to C# myself, but thought that it has something to do with `delegate`s, so I googled and found an Article about [C# Delegates at tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_delegates.htm) and adapted the learned (refreshed syntax) to what I understand the problem is. Maybe this looks too complicated for experienced C# programmers, but maybe it helps:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Rextester
{
    public abstract class Base {
        public abstract void show();
    }
    public class Dep1: Base {
        public override void show() {
            Console.WriteLine("Dep1");
        }
    }
    public class Dep2: Base {
        public override void show() {
            Console.WriteLine("Dep2");
        }
    }

    public delegate Base Maker();

    public class Program
    {

        public static Base MakeDep1() { 
            return new Dep1(); 
        }
        public static Base MakeDep2() { 
            return new Dep2(); 
        }

        static Maker[] makers = new Maker[] {MakeDep1, MakeDep2};

        static Random rand = new Random();

        public static Base MakeRandom() { 
            return makers[rand.Next(makers.Length)](); 
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Base> objs = new List<Base>();

            // build a list of "random-generated" objects
            for (int i=0; i<10; ++i) {
                objs.Add(MakeRandom());
            }

            foreach (Base obj in objs) {
                obj.show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the running demo see https://rextester.com/NAAUJ16900